# Fastest way to insert a 2D array into a (larger) 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

Say there's two 2D arrays, `a` and `b`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(3, 4)
b = np.random.zeros(8, 8)
```

and `b` is always larger than `a` over both axes.

*(Edit: `b` is initialized as an array of zeros, to reflect the fact that all elements not occupied by `a` will remain zero.)*

**Question**. What's the *fastest* or *most Pythonic* way to "insert" `a` into `b`?

So far I've tried 2 things:

1. Using `np.pad` to "turn" `a` into an array of shape `(8, 8)`
2. Loop through every row in `a` and place it in some the corresponding row in `b`

What I **haven't** tried is using a doubly-nested loop to iterate over every element of `a`, since I think that's not performance-friendly.

**Motivation**. Each array `a` is a tiny character, and I'd like to feed each character to a neural net that accepts *flattened* arrays of shape `(8, 8)`, ie. arrays of shape `(64,)`. (I *think* I can't simply flatten `a` to one dimension and pad it with zeros because then its two-dimensional structure gets warped, so, rather, I must first "reshape" it into `(8, 8)`, right?) There's a few millions of characters.

Comment: You speak of padding with zeroes in the last paragraph, but in the example you present `b` with random values. So what do you need: `a` padded with the values from `b`,  or padded with zeroes? Is the padding at the right and bottom?

Comment: what is meant by "insert"?

Comment: why not `b[?:?, ?:?] = a`? That is slice a matching block of `b` as place to put `a`

Comment: Do you want to insert a in the centre of b or a corner or somewhere else? Do you pad the other elements with 0 or leave them unchanged? Can you give an example of a and b and the resulted array?

Comment: @trincot Whoops, `b` should actually be `np.zeros`. Also, the padding should ideally be centered, but the top left corner is also good.

Comment: @Allen The other elements are padded with 0.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, so far something like `b[:a.shape[0], :a.shape[1]] = a` seems the best choice! I totally missed that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about :

```
b[:a.shape[0],:a.shape[1]] = a
```

Note I assumed `a` is to be placed at the begining of `b` but you could refine it a bit to put `a` anywhere:

```
a0,a1=1,1
b[a0:a0+a.shape[0],a1:a1+a.shape[1]] = a
```

Answer (score 2):

More generally you can determine the position where you want to insert the array if you create a tuple of slices (this works for arbitary dimensions):

```
>>> a = np.random.random((5,5))
>>> b = np.ones((3,3))

>>> edge_coordinate = (0,0)
>>> slicer = tuple(slice(edge, edge+i) for edge, i in zip(edge_coordinate, b.shape))
>>> a[slicer] = b
>>> a
array([[ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.14206495,  0.36385016],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.08861402,  0.7888898 ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.1975496 ,  0.13345192],
       [ 0.550487  ,  0.22471952,  0.47050879,  0.04669643,  0.13480528],
       [ 0.25139511,  0.06499812,  0.42247189,  0.05840351,  0.74735495]])
```

by varying the `edge_coordinate` you can vary the position:

```
>>> a = np.random.random((5,5))
>>> b = np.ones((3,3))

>>> edge_coordinates = (1,1)  # changed
>>> slicer = tuple(slice(edge, edge+i) for edge, i in zip(edge_coordinates, b.shape))
>>> a[slicer] = b
>>> a
array([[ 0.21385714,  0.68789872,  0.3915475 ,  0.67342566,  0.05642307],
       [ 0.19778658,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.70717406],
       [ 0.73678924,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.90285997],
       [ 0.39709332,  1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.96959814],
       [ 0.89627195,  0.21295355,  0.72598992,  0.80749348,  0.76660287]])
```

Ideally one could make a function of it - if you regularly use it.

Comment: But isn't this fancy indexing, which in general creates a new array? I just want to get a _view_ of a previously-allocated-array and write to it.

Comment: @étale-cohomology No, a tuple of slices is regular indexing and returns a view.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use padding.

if you want to place a in the top left corner:

```
np.pad(a,((0,5),(0,4)),'constant')
```

if you want to place a in centre:

```
np.pad(a,((2,3),(2,2)),'constant')
```

Comment: But is this the fastest and most natural way? Doesn't this create a new array on the fly (which I'd rather not do)?